# Connect passive STS to active STS

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, wif

at the moment I have a single active sts. The sts validates the user with a custom user/password validator. The sts is used for different windows services. Now I'd like to write a asp.net application that uses the sts for login. Later I'd like to change the sts authentication method(e.g. to windows authentication).

What is the best solution for connecting a asp.net site to an active sts. Do I need a passive sts? Do you have an easy example for me?(example code?)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you would normally use a passive STS. Refer [Get Started with Windows Identity Foundation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3487.get-started-with-windows-identity-foundation-wif.aspx). There is a ton of stuff in the Identity Training Kit mentioned here.

You could also have a look at [Identity Server](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/) which is open source and implements the passive profile.

**Update:**

If you are talking about two different STS, you just federate them.

If you are talking about one STS, they can support both. The only difference is the endpoints for the active and passive connections. "Identity Server" and ADFS both allow this.

If you are talking about "Identity delegation" see [Identity Delegation with AD FS 2.0 Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-identity-delegation-step-by-step-guide%28WS.10%29.aspx). There is an example in the WIF SDK under Samples / End-to-end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have you an example that shows how to connect a passive sts to an active sts.(Howto Transfer Windows-Identity to active STS; Howto send the active sts token back to the asp.net webpage?)

Comment: I seems that [Identity Server has moved to github](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3).